# Python: using regex on a complicated list of multiple CSS selectors to extract their # and . tags

Tags: python, regex

Is there an easier way of checking if a string matches a specific pattern and retrieving the group from that pattern?

I want to go through a file of with {readlines} and collect any lines that have stuff between the quotes:

```
 **{**

 **"simpleSelectors": [**

 "*",**
```

if those are lines in my file, my list should have ['simpleSelectors','*'] in it

```
regexline = re.compile('\"(.*)\"')
for i in css:
    if re.search(regexline, i):
        x = re.search(regexline, i)
        inputs.append(x.group(1))
```

Comment: Hi, it's a little bit hard to understand what you're asking - perhaps show a more complete example of your file, as well as the exact output you would expect? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop over each line. And no need to escape the quotation marks in your regex:

```
import re

css='{\n\n"simpleSelectors": [\n\n"*",'

inputs = []
regexline = re.compile('"(.*)"')
matches = re.findall(regexline, css)
print( matches) # ['simpleSelectors', '*']
```

**EDIT:**
To subdivide your matches, use

```
matches = [item for match in re.findall(regexline, css) for item in match.split()]
```

Comment: This is great. There are some lines in the following format: "item-1 item_2". If I wanted to separate any items with spaces, what would be the most efficient way, can this be done without looping?

Comment: See my edit above. It will only work if you are guaranteed that spaces *only* occur between (not within) items inside your quotation marks.

Comment: That's very very good. You just saved me about 20 lines of code!

Answer (score 2):

You can use re.findall on all the lines using:

```
matches = re.findall(regexline, css)
```